# how to rollback a update query in sugar crm

Tags: mysql, sugarcrm, rollback

I have installed the Sugar CRM and I want that the Sales executive can make changes to the inserted data but that data should reflect only once the Admin approves it.

My logic is that I have to rollback the update query of that employee(sales executive).
Please let me know how I can implement it.
I am newbie in sugar crm if there is any documentation kindly let me know 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would leverage the audit tables in Sugar to do this. Simply query the audit table to find the previous value and re-instate that.